# Query required for given output

Tags: sql, oracle

Supose I have data in below format

```
FIELD1   F2       F3 
LIN0_TMP    A0  1
LIN0_TMP    B0  2
LIN0_TMP    C0  3
LIN_TMP     A   1
LIN_TMP     B   2
LIN_TMP     C   3
LIN_TMP     D   4
LIN2_TMP    A2  1
LIN2_TMP    B2  2
LIN2_TMP    C2  3
LIN2_TMP    D2  4
```

i WANT output in below format using oracle sql query.

```
FIELD1   F2       F3   FLOW
    LIN0_TMP    A0  1 FLOW1
    LIN0_TMP    B0  2 FLOW1
    LIN0_TMP    C0  3 FLOW1
    LIN_TMP     A   1 FLOW2
    LIN_TMP     B   2 FLOW2
    LIN_TMP     C   3 FLOW2
    LIN_TMP     D   4 FLOW2
    LIN2_TMP    A2  1 FLOW3 
    LIN2_TMP    B2  2 FLOW3
    LIN2_TMP    C2  3 FLOW3
    LIN2_TMP    D2  4 FLOW3
```

Number of record for field1 is not fixed for each LIN_TMP value..

Comment: And what magic spell determines the value of the FLOW column?  If you want some help you need to give us the business logic you need to implement.

Comment: whenever number 1 is encountered it means a flow is started .. so it started with FLOW1.. for next 1 encountered it will named as FLOW2

Comment: Yes but how is FIELD1 ordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses an analytic sum to generate a running total of the number of times F3 = 1.

```
select field1
      , f2
      , f3
      , 'FLOW'||trim(to_char(rnk))
from 
     (select field1
      , f2
      , f3
      , sum(case when f3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
     over (order by field1, f3 range between unbounded preceding and current row) rnk
    from your_table )
```

Here is [the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a39e2/2).

As I mentioned in my comment, your sort order for FIELD1 is wack, so you will need to supply your own ORDER BY column for the window clause.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.. I have one doubt what if FIELD1 is just a random non repeating value, Then How can I proceed..

Comment: If you can't use FIELD1 you will have to find some other column to sort on.  It appears that F2 has some kind of grouping, based on the trailing value.  So you could use pattern-matching on that (SUBSTR or REGEXP).   Unless the sample data you posted for F2 is bogus as well, in which case you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

And here's another alternative which finds the distinct values from FIELD1, assigns a number to the 'flow' based on the ROWNUM of the distinct FIELD1 values, and then just concatenates everything back together:

```
SELECT t.FIELD1, t.F2, t.F3, 'FLOW' || FLOW_NUM AS FLOW
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
  INNER JOIN (SELECT FIELD1, ROWNUM AS FLOW_NUM
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1
                        FROM YOUR_TABLE 
                        ORDER BY FIELD1 DESC)) t2
    ON (t2.FIELD1 = t.FIELD1)
  ORDER BY FLOW, F2, F3
```

Tweak this as needed.

Share and enjoy.